# Вычислить сумму квадратов чисел, принадлежащих промежутку (A,B), стоящих на местах, кратных 4; подсчитать кол-во нулей во всем массиве

Tags: pascal, turbopascal

> Вычислить сумму квадратов чисел, принадлежащих промежутку (A,B), стоящих на местах, кратных 4; подсчитать кол-во нулей во всем массиве.

```
program 17; 
var 
    c:array[1..20] of real; 
    s,kv4,kr,a,b:real; 
    n,i,nul:integer; 
begin 
    writeln ('vvedite kol-vo el massiva'); 
    readln (n); 
    writeln ('vvedite promeshutok ot a do b'); 
    readln (a,b); 
    writeln ('vvedite el massiva'); 
    for i:=1 to n do 
        readln (c[i]); 
    s:=0; 
    nul:=0; 
    for i:=1 to n do 
        if (c[i]>a) and (c[i]) then 
        begin 

        end; 
        if
```

kv4 квадрат числа

kr кратные

nul Нули.

Comment: по моему у вас код не полностью скопирован + путой begin - end

Comment: да. я знаю. я написал что это всё на что я додумался

Comment: постройте сначала псевдокод (т е логику) а потом переводите эту логику на язык паскаля. Например у вас `c` - массив с 20ю элементами внутри. Получается `n` должно быть строго от `1` до `20` иначе (если пользователь введет 40) то у вас вылетет `exeption`, т к c[40] не существует

Comment: уже строил логику. К сожалению у школоты она тугая. А сижу уже 3 часа над этой задачей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
program elements_of_array;
var
  arr: array of real;
  n: integer;
  i: integer;
  a, b: real;
  sum: real;
  nulls: integer; 
begin
  write('Количество элементов массива: ');
  readln(n);

  SetLength(arr, n);

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      write(i + 1, ' элемент массива: ');
      readln(arr[i]);
    end;

  writeln('Массив: ', arr);

  write('Промежуток (A, B): ');
  readln(a, b);

  sum := 0;
  nulls := 0;
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if (arr[i] = 0) then
        begin
          inc(nulls);
          continue;
        end;
      if (((i + 1) Mod 4 = 0) and (arr[i] > a) and (arr[i] < b)) then
        sum := sum + arr[i] * arr[i];
    end;

  writeln('Количество нулей в массиве: ', nulls);
  writeln('Сумма элементов: ', sum);
end.
```

**UPD**: [реализация динамического массива с помощью указателей](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42519050/dynamic-array-in-turbo-pascal)

```
program elements_of_array;
const
  MaxSize = 100;
type
  TArray = array [0..MaxSize] of real;
  PArray = ^TArray;
var
  arr: PArray;
  n: integer;
  i: integer;
  a, b: real;
  sum: real;
  nulls: integer;
begin
  getmem(arr, sizeof(real) * MaxSize);
  fillchar(arr^, sizeof(real) * MaxSize, #0);

  write('Количество элементов массива: ');
  readln(n);

  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      write(i + 1, ' элемент массива: ');
      readln(arr^[i]);
    end;

  write('Промежуток (A, B): ');
  readln(a, b);

  sum := 0;
  nulls := 0;
  for i := 0 to n - 1 do
    begin
      if (arr^[i] = 0) then
        begin
          inc(nulls);
          continue;
        end;
      if (((i + 1) Mod 4 = 0) and (arr^[i] > a) and (arr^[i] < b)) then
        sum := sum + arr^[i] * arr^[i];
    end;

  writeln('Количество нулей в массиве: ', nulls);
  writeln('Сумма элементов: ', sum);
end.
```

Comment: setlenght кидает и пишет неизвестный индетификатор

Comment: Это потому что в турбопаскале динамических массивов нет, setlength к массивам не применяется

Comment: @MaximQwerty обновил ответ с учетом Turbo Pascal

Answer (score 0):

```
Program test; 

uses crt,math;
var 
    c:array  of integer; // Объявляем динамический массив
    n,i,a,b,sum_for_null,sum_sqware:integer;
begin
clrscr; // очистка экрана
sum_for_null := 0; // инициализируем переменную для подсчета нулей
sum_sqware := 0; // инициализируем переменную для подсчета квадратов
writeln('Ведите границы промежутка a и b ');
readln(a,b); // Вводим границы
setlength(c,n); // устанавливаем длину динамическому массиву 
for i:=a to b - 1 do // ходим циклом от одной границы ко второй
 begin
    readln(c[i]); // считываем значения
 end;
for i:=a to b - 1 do // ходим циклом от одной границы ко второй
begin
   if c[i] = 0 then  // если значение равно 0
   begin
   sum_for_null := sum_for_null + 1; // увеличиваем счетчик нулей на 1
   end;
   if (i / 4 = Round(i / 4)) then // если текущий номер массива разделенного на 4 равен округленному текущему номеру деленному на 4 (т е кратен 4ом) 
   begin
    sum_sqware := sum_sqware + Sqr(c[i]); //увеличиваем текущую сумму на квадрат элемента 
   end;
end;
writeln('количество нулей в промежутку = ',sum_for_null); // выводим кол-во нулей
writeln('сумма квадратов числе на местах, кратных 4 = ',sum_sqware); // выводим сумму квадратов элементов, кратных 4-ом 
readln // пауза
end.
```

Comment: `i / 4 = Round(i / 4)` про `Mod` не слышали?

Comment: А чем так не нравится? Скорость падает, чтоли?